# What kind of compound absorption the 365nm UV light on TLC

Tags: analytical-chemistry, photochemistry

What kind of compound absorption the 365nm UV light?

compounds that has benzene ring or conjugated pi bond, make a fluorescence on 254 nm UV on TLC. 
what kind of moiety(functional group) make fluorescence on 365nm UV on TLC

Comment: Though I don't think this is worth a full answer on a closed question, it might be usefull to know that some TLC plates have been functionalized to fluoresce at the wavelength used to check for compounds. Depending on the compounds that have run on the TLC plate, the fluorescence is quenched and therefore you can see a spot.

Answer (score 1):

*Your question is almost impossible to answer - it simply is too broad.*

1. Excitation spectra of fluorescent organic compounds typically aren't sharp lines but consist of one (or more) bands. Even if the maximum of the excitation spectrum isn't located at $\lambda = \textrm{365 nm}$, **monochromatic** irradiation at that wavelength will excite **a lot** of different compounds (and even compound classes) which then deactivate by fluorescence.
2. Your light source does not emit monochromatic radiation! Hand lamps used to inspect TLCs typically have coated low-pressure mercury lamps. While the maximum of the radiation density might be centred around 360 nm, the full with at half maximum is - roughly estimated - about 30 nm or more. This means that there's even more compounds that might get excited by the emission of the hand lamp.

In summary, there's no exhaustive answer to your question, but just to name some compounds that are potential candidates:

[image: possible structures that match UV requirements]

- Diphenylacetylene (**1**)
- 1,6-Diphenylhexatriene (DPH, **2**)
- 4',6-diamidino-2-phenylindole (DAPI, **3**)
- 6,8-difluoro-7-hydroxy-4-methylcoumarin (DIFMU, **4**)